# Delete Specific row in rdlc report

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I using [rdlc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067.aspx) report in my project.I have number of row in it

and i want select dynamically specific row from it for delete

how can i do that?

Is there any way for delete specific row in run time?